# Responsive Email Targeting Desktop

Tags: outlook, media-queries, html-email

I am having a hard time targeting the desktop with the media query below.

I have this media query that i want to hide a tr on anything bigger than a mobile phone

```
            @media screen and (min-device-width: 620px){
            tr[id = mobileHide] {
                    display: none !important;
                    width: 0px !important;
                }
            }
```

It is worth noting that this is working when i view the HTML in the browser.

Is this an issue with Outlook perhaps? Do i need to do a condition tag for outlook to hide this tr?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Outlook [doesn't support CSS selectors](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Another thing to note is that depending on your MS Exchange server, sometimes your media queries are blocked entirely, so just confirm they are working at all.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible.

Try '@media all,, instead of `screen`. Pretty sure that will solve it.

.. If not try to hide the `td`, and not the `tr` like in your code

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (min-width:600px){
    .desktop-hide{display:none;}
}
```

And the the HTML markup

```
<tr class="desktop-hide">
    <td>
        <p>Text only shown in Mobile clients that support media queries</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps. Remember that many Email clients don't support media queries, so make sure it looks good even if the tr shows.